# Can't see objects, only outlines

Tags: objects

I can only see outlines of objects. I might have accidentally hit a key that changed a setting, just not sure which one.

[image: Can only see object outline here.]

Answer (score 1):

You are in *Wireframe* viewport shading mode, switch to *Solid* mode (shortcut <kbd>Z</kbd>):

[image]